# open init.rc file in android and append one line

Tags: android

I want to add one line to init.rc file in android. So please tell me how to open and append one line to that file.
It will be great pleasure to me if anybody can explain it in detail because I am new in android.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `system/core/rootdir/init.rc` path and directly modify this file as per your requirement.

Comment: Do i need to root the phone to modify?

Comment: This response assumes you are building your ROM from source